# PHP parallel File writes

Tags: php, filesystems, fwrite, legacy-app

I have an old application that uses files instead of a DB to store user data in an xml. All totally legacy. Until the  migration to a DB has finished, I need support the current state.

The problem is that sometimes (unreproducible) it occurred, that the file contents were not written completely. This caused the xml files to not be complete and therefore to be invalid.

My assumption is, that the server can't handle the amount of parallel file writes.

Note, that parallel does not mean many scripts write one file, but each script that writes the user content writes for one user per call. There are up to 100 calls to the script in peak times.

The script uses the standard fwrite functionality to write an incoming xml string to the file. No appending, just replacing the whole content, which works in the tests. The problem only occurs when a greater amount of users use the application.

Is there a way to queue the file writes or delay the script calls?

Please comment, if the description is insufficient.

Comment: Could it be something is trying to read the file while its being written? If so you could try locking the file during write then other reads will queue until the write releases the lock

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I though the same thing, in case this is the issue you might need to create a wrapper function that call fwrite() function and inside wrapper you will have a queue for the files that you are gonna write the users content to, and you should be using [flock()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) function to check if its locked and being modified, that might be a one the idea I have now for this issue.

Comment: Ok I will check that tonight and update my description, if necessary. Thank you.